# Place tables in the middle of the page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have two tables, table1 and table 2. I want table 1 in the middle of page 1, table 2 in the middle of page 2.

First, I tried,

```
\begin{table}[htbp]  
\input{table1}  
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]  
\input{table2}  
\end{table}
```

But then both table1 and table 2 are on page 1.

Second, I tried

```
\begin{table}[htbp]  
\input{table1}  
\end{table}
\clearpage
\begin{table}[htbp]  
\input{table2}  
\end{table}
```

Then table1 is in the middle of page 1, but table2 is on the top of (rather than in the middle) page 2.

I would appreciate any and all advice on what to do.. Thank you!!

Comment: I put \clearpage before every table. This places all tables on the top of each page. So the question changes to, how do I place a table after \clearpage in the middle of the page rather than at the top. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "middle of the page", do you mean you want them in the middle of page, with no other text on the page, or do you want them surrounded by text?

Comment: @Mark: This is Appendix, so simply one table per page.

Comment: \begin{table}[p]

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reply. I tried it already, but it has no effect..

Comment: @Mark Sorry for the confusion. It works perfectly well! Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome.  I notice you asked a question here yesterday.  Did that ever get resolved?  P.S.  good luck with the thesis  :)

Comment: @Mark, do you intend to convert your comment, which solve the OP problem, to answer?

Comment: I'm too lazy.  If someone nags me I will, but I kind of hope someone else does.

Answer (score 3):

Since Zarko said so:

```
\begin{table}[p]  
\input{table1}  
\end{table}
\clearpage
\begin{table}[p]  
\input{table2}  
\end{table}
```

:)